# Django ORM - Dynamically add When to Case

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a list of lists

```
my_list= [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    ...
]
```

I'd like to annotate some values like this:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Case, When, Value

MyModel.objects.filter(...).annotate(label=Case(When(some_value__in=my_list[0] then=Value('first list')), output_field=CharField()))
```

Now I need add a similar `When` for the other lists in `my_list`, but my_list could have different lengths.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [`Case` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) can contain any number of `When`s. You can create a list of `When` expressions and then unpack it into a `Case`:

```
whens = [When(some_value__in=l, then=Value('list #{}'.format(i)))\
            for i, l in enumerate(my_list)]

MyModel.objects.filter(...).annotate(label=Case(*whens, output_field=CharField()))
```

Comment: Omg `*list` was completly out of my mind today. I'll test it.

Comment: Perfect!, I just changed a little things. Thanks for your time.